# Dotnet Core MVC Angular Issue Publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, azure, .net-core

Project is mostly the default angular 4 template from the Dotnet Core 2.0 templates list.
Locally the project runs fine, except it *Sometimes* fails in release mode. It fails every time I try to publish with the same error.

`ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
Module not found(0,0): Error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in 'C:\projectpath\ClientApp'
     @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95
Error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.`

I added a .angular-cli.json for what it's worth.
I have read that this error is indicative of an error elsewhere in the code but I can't see any other error in the publish output. Has anybody else ran into this issue when publishing to an Azure WebApp the angular default template?

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproduction?

Comment: Could this be issue with angular-cli
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4551